# Closed form of $\int_{[0,1]} \frac{dw}{1-wz}$ involving Ln?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, contour-integration, holomorphic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

Related to [Why is $\int_{[0,1]} \frac{dw}{1-wz}$ is holomorphic in unit disc?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860170/)

I think if

> $$f(z) := \int_{[0,1]} \frac{dw}{1-wz} = -\frac1z\operatorname{Ln}(1-z)1_{z\ne0} + 1_{z=0},$$

then $f(z)$ is continuous on $D[0,1]$.

For $z=0$,

$$\int_{[0,1]} \frac{dw}{1-wz} = \int_{[0,1]} \frac{dw}{1} = \int_0^1 dw = 1\tag{*}$$

For $z \ne 0$, consider the real integral where $z \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$

$$\int_{0}^1 \frac{dw}{1-wz} = -\frac{1}{z}\ln|1-z|$$

1. Can we extend this to $\mathbb C$ to conclude that ([Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20(1%2F(1-wz))%20dw,%20%7Cz%7C%3C1))

$$\int_{[0,1]} \frac{dw}{1-wz} = -\frac{1}{z}\operatorname{Ln}|1-z|?$$

It seems pretty tough to integrate $$\int_{[0,1]} \frac{dw}{1-wz} = \int_{0}^1 \Re \frac{dw}{1-wz} + i\int_{0}^1 \Im \frac{dw}{1-wz}$$

2. What's the relevance of $\operatorname{Re}(z) \le 1$ ([Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20(1%2F(1-wz))%20dw)) ? Luckily that's the assumption given in the problem, but I don't see how that's relevant in computing the integral.
3. (*) Btw, why don't we actually have $\int_{[0,1]} \frac{dw}{1} = 0$ by [Cor 4.20 to Cauchy's Theorem](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html)? I guess we don't have that $[0,1] \sim_{D[0,1]} 0$.

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $w\in[0,1]$, $\log(1-wz)$ is well-defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[1,\infty)$, so we can integrate along the path $[0,1]$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,1]}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{1-wz}
&=\frac1z\int_{[0,1]}\frac{z\,\mathrm{d}w}{1-wz}\\
&=\left.-\frac1z\log(1-wz)\,\right|_0^1\\[3pt]
&=-\frac{\log(1-z)}z
\end{align}
$$
with a branch cut along $[1,\infty)$. Note that if $z\not\in[1,\infty)$, then $1-wz$ is bounded away from $0$ for $w\in[0,1]$.

---

Another approach using a series which converges for $|wz|\lt1$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,1]}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{1-wz}
&=\int_{[0,1]}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty w^kz^k\right)\mathrm{d}w\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1w^kz^k\,\mathrm{d}w\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k+1}\\
&=-\frac{\log(1-z)}z
\end{align}
$$
which converges for $|z|\lt1$.

Comment: Thanks robjohn! About z=0, what's the integral of 1 over [0,1] please? From Calculus I think it's 1. In complex analysis, I guess it's also 1 but which assumption in Cor 4.20 to Cauchy's theorem is violated? G-contractible?

Comment: Robjohn, is your log any branch? Also, what's the relevance of |z|<1?

Comment: As mentioned, there is a branch cut in the first approach along $[1,\infty)$. In the second approach, the series converges where $|z|\lt1$.

Comment: Cauchy's theorem is not violated: the contour is not closed.

Comment: oh I forgot g-contractible implies closed. Also, I said assumptions of. Thanks!