# Find radius of of $\sum k^n z^k$, $\sum \frac{z^k}{k^k}$, $\sum \cos(k)z^k$, $\sum 4^k (z-2)^k$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html) Exer 7.33(b)(e)(f)(g)

> [image]

(b) What's the role of $n \in \mathbb Z$? I guess it's in the part where $\lim_{k} |\frac{k+1}{k}|^n = |\lim_{k}\frac{k+1}{k}|^n$ like $x^n$ is continuous if $n \in \mathbb Z$?

(e) [$R = \infty$? WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%20%3D%201%20to%20infinity%7D%20(z%2Fk)%5Ek) just says converges by ratio test (I used root).

(f) [$R=1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%20%3D%200%20to%20infinity%7D%20cos(k)%7Cz%7C%5Ek)? I use Exer 7.27 (*) to say that since $|\cos(k)| \le 1 \ \forall k \ge 0$ and $\lim_k \cos(k) \ne 0$, we have resp, $R \ge 1$ and $R \le 1$.

(g) [$R=\frac 1 4$? WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%20%3D%200%20to%20infinity%7D%20(4z-8)%5Ek) initially says that series converges for the equivalent of $|z-2| < \frac 1 4$ but then later says that the series diverges by the 'geometric series test'.

---

(*)

> [image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(b) If $n \in \mathbb Z$, then $z^n$ is continuous. Thus, $\lim_{k} |\frac{k+1}{k}|^n = |\lim_{k}\frac{k+1}{k}|^n$.

(e) [$R = \infty$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%20%3D%201%20to%20infinity%7D%20(z%2Fk)%5Ek)

by root or ratio test.

(f) [$R=1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%20%3D%200%20to%20infinity%7D%20cos(k)%7Cz%7C%5Ek)

By Exer 7.27 (*), since $|\cos(k)| \le 1 \ \forall k \ge 0$ and $\lim_k \cos(k) \ne 0$, we have resp, $R \ge 1$ and $R \le 1$.

(g) [$R=\frac 1 4$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%20%3D%200%20to%20infinity%7D%20(4z-8)%5Ek).

Power series usually diverge. It's just that that converge for some subset of $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

---

(*)

> [image]